# How to create a unrepeatable connection inside a connecting table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: date and employee, and a third table labeled attendance (connection table) with two foreign keys that are date_id and employee_id.

I need to make that only one entry for the same date_id and the same employee_id is possible.

The thing is: The third table is where I store my data on did the employee show up to work on that date. If I have two entries with the same date_id and the same employee_id, I will have one person both be at work and on vacation on the same day.

So how do I alter the attendance table so the same combination of date_id and employee_id doesn't repeat itself?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can u provide some records samples, please

Comment: Hello and thank you.
attendance table -
attendance_id (INT 10, AI, primary key)
date_id (int 10, Foreign key, connecting table date)
employee_id (int 10, Foreign key, connecting table employee)
evidention (enum, "1" "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "BO", "GO")

and I have these two entries in that table:

attendance_id (4), date_id (72021), employee_id (5), evidention ("8")

||||| attendance_id (5), date_id (72021), employee_id (5), evidention ("BO")

which basically means that employee with id 5 was both present and on sick leave on 5th of July 2021